# Is it possible to convert variables to literals in getter creation?

Tags: javascript, getter

For example, if I want to split every property of an object into a normal value and a `getter`, I can't use a for in because the get function would be `return this["_" + i]`. What I'd expect is `i === "name"` -> create `getter` -> `getter` returns `this._name`, but since `"_" + i` is only evaluated when it runs, the `getter` would look for `this["_" + i]`.

Which means `getter`s can't be used with any kind of modular object. They can only be defined one by one, and they can't use any variables except globals and properties of the object they're on.

Is there any kind of workaround to that? I'd use the function constructor, but there's no place to use it.

Comment: Sounds like you should use `.forEach(function(i) {...})` instead of `for (var i of ...) {...}`. Please share more of your code to make a precise answer easier.

Comment: You can use `Object.defineProperty`/`Object.defineProperties` to add your getters and setters instead, which would work fine with any constructed string name. But since you provide no code, we cannot know how you are currently doing it.

Comment: Please post the code that does not work. It sounds a bit like a problem with a [closure in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572), but we can only guess.

Comment: "*the getter would look for `this["_" + i]`.*" - and that's fine, as `"_" + i` would evaluate to the string `"_name"`. But no, you cannot convert it to a *literal*.